Django добавление данных в другую таблицу
Начал изучать django. Столкнулся с таким вопросом. Чтобы добавлять пользователей необходимо сделать модель и применить миграции. А если я хочу добавлять данные в БД но в другую таблицу. Например база называется database.db и в ней 2 таблицы. Одна по умолчанию, куда сохраняются данные после миграции heelo.person, а я хочу чтобы сохранялись данные в таблицу Users. Как мне это реализовать. Буду очень благодарен кто объяснит.

Необходимо просто подключаться к бд и делать sql запросы?
